# How to delete tables in sqlite database using wildcard search?

Tags: vb.net, sqlite

I am using a sqlite database in my vb.net application. I want to delete tables from my database using wildcard search. For that I have use following command

```
DROP TABLE LIKE '%FunctionAnalysis%';
```

but this gives me error as

```
[10:17:56] Error while executing SQL query: near "'%FunctionAnalysis%'": syntax error
```

There might be some error in the syntax as I am new to SQLite and SQL queries.
Please help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DROP TABLE statement works only with a single, fixed table name.

You can execute a query like this to get all table names you want:

```sql
SELECT name
FROM sqlite_master
WHERE type = 'table'
  AND name LIKE '%FunctionAnalysis%'
```

Then your program has to construct and execute a DROP TABLE statement with each returned value.